# Задача Очередь в магазине не проходит по времени

Tags: c++

Задача E. Очередь в магазине
Имя входного файла: стандартный ввод
Имя выходного файла: стандартный вывод
Ограничение по времени: 1 секунда
Ограничение по памяти: 256 мегабайт
В одном известном магазине случилась распродажа, однако администрация не учла одну проблему: в магазине всего одна касса! Сразу после начала распродажи возле кассы организовалась
длинная очередь. Никто не любит очереди, поэтому у покупателей постепенно возрастает уровень
агрессии. От вас требуется рассмотреть процесс продвижения очереди.
Могут происходить события трёх типов:

1. В конец очереди встал человек с уровнем агрессии a;
2. Первый человек в очереди начал ругаться с кассиром, в результате чего уровень его агрессии
   увеличился на x, а уровень агрессии каждого из остальных людей в очереди (если в очереди
   стоит не один человек) увеличился на y;
3. Первый человек в очереди оплатил покупку и ушёл из магазина.
   От вас требуется обработать N событий. Будем считать, что изначально очередь пуста. Так как
   администрация магазина заботится о своей репутации, им важно знать, насколько агрессивными их
   покупатели уходят из магазина. Поэтому для каждого события третьего типа нужно определить
   уровень агрессии человека, который ушёл из магазина.

Формат входных данных
В первой строке записано одно число N — количество событий (2 6 N 6 300000).
В каждой из следующих N строк содержится описание очередного события:
• 1 a, если произошло событие первого типа;
• 2 x y, если произошло событие второго типа;
• 3, если произошло событие третьего типа.
Для всех событий верно, что 1 6 a, x, y 6 109
. Гарантируется, что события второго и третьего
типов происходят только в том случае, если в очереди есть хотя бы один человек. Также гарантируется, что после N событий в очереди не останется ни одного человека. Возможны случаи, когда
первый человек в очереди несколько раз подряд ссорится с кассиром.
Формат выходных данных
Для каждого запроса третьего типа выведите одно число — уровень агрессии человека, который
ушёл из магазина. Каждое число следует выводить на отдельной строке.
Пример

стандартный ввод

8

1 4

1 2

2 6 1

3

2 10 20

1 1

3

3

стандартный вывод

10

13

1

Замечание

Сначала в очередь встали два человека с уровнями агрессии 4 и 2 соответственно. Затем первый
человек поссорился с кассиром, после чего уровни агрессии людей стали равны 10 и 3. После этого
первый человек ушёл из очереди, а второй поссорился с кассиром. Теперь уровень его агрессии
равен 13. Затем в очередь встал человек с уровнем агрессии 1, после чего оба человека ушли из
магазина.

Решал с помощью этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получился такой код:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long d = 0;
    vector <long> queue;
    int n, value, x, y;
    cin >> n;
    for(; n > 0; n--){
        char command;
        cin >> command;
        switch(command){
            case '1':
                cin >> value;
                queue.push_back((value - d));
                break;
            case '2':
                cin >> x >> y;
                d += y;
                queue[0] += (x - y);
                break;
            default:
                cout << (queue[0] + d) << endl;
                queue.erase(queue.begin());
            }
    }
}
```

Но он не проходит по времени
Подскажите, как его можно оптимизировать?`

**UPD1:**

Ответ выше помог, на ещё одни тест продвинулся, но всё ещё не хватает скорости

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long d = 0;
    deque <long> queue;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(; n > 0; n--){
        char command;
        cin >> command;
        switch(command){
        case '1':
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            queue.emplace_back(value - d);
            break;
        case '2':
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> y;
            d += y;
            queue[0] += x - y;
            break;
        default:
            cout << (queue.front() + d) << endl;
            queue.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2**
Пошёл по совету, сделал с переменной фронт

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long d = 0, front = 0;
    vector <long> queue;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(; n > 0; n--){
        char command;
        cin >> command;
        switch(command){
        case '1':
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            queue.emplace_back(value - d);
            break;
        case '2':
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> y;
            d += y;
            queue[front] += x - y;
            break;
        default:
            cout << (queue[front] + d);
            ++front;
        }
    }
}
```

Как и было предложено, реализовал всё на деке. Не знаю, что можно изменить?

**UPD3:**

Продвижения не стало, на данный момент быстрее всего работает следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long d = 0;
    deque <long> queue;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(; n > 0; n--){
        char command;
        cin >> command;
        switch(command){
        case '1':
            int value;
            cin >> value;
            queue.emplace_back(value - d);
            break;
        case '2':
            int x, y;
            cin >> x >> y;
            d += y;
            queue[0] += x - y;
            break;
        default:
            cout << (queue[0] + d) << endl;
            queue.pop_front();
        }
    }
}
```

На последнем проходящем тесте(32 / 35) он показывает 0.568 с

Comment: Решение же - ясно сказано - на 40 баллов. А **полное** решение стоит 60 баллов. И требует иного алгоритма.

Comment: нет, решение на 40 баллов - просто создать вектор и повторять действие, я же использовал имеено алгоритм для полного балла, смотри внимательнее код и решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Медленно работает `queue.erase(queue.begin());`. Удаление элемента из начала вектора приводит к копированию всех элементов вектора на одну позицию влево. Если вектор длинный, это займёт заметное время. Замените вектор на дек (deque) и обработку поменяйте на методы дека (`push_back`, `pop_front`).

Comment: Помогло продвинуться на один тест

Answer (score 0):

Ясно же написано: заведем некоторую переменную d, изначально равную нулю, в
которой мы будем накапливать некоторое значение агрессивности, которое нужно прибавить **ко всем людям в очереди**
Ваш код вообще не рабочий, потому что в Case 2 вы изменяете только первый элемент очереди, а нужно изменять все элементы.